# Sidebar show posts by current category also in single post

Tags: posts, sidebar

I've got this code that works fine in the sidebar and it shows all the related post for the category, but when I click on a single post not works (shows recent articles).

I would like the same behaviour also in single post.

What I have to add in the code?

```
add_filter( 'tve_dash_enqueue_frontend', '__return_true' );

add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args');
function my_widget_posts_args($args) {
if ( is_category() ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    return array(
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'no_found_rows' => true, 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'cat' => $cat -> term_id//the current category id
         );
}
else {//keeps the normal behaviour if we are not in category context
    return $args;

}}
```

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let me first describe the full code in code comments. Please read the comments carefully-

```
// By this below code you are returning TRUE to the filter 'tve_dash_enqueue_frontend' filter. Which is I think, is turning something on.
add_filter( 'tve_dash_enqueue_frontend', '__return_true' );

// Here you are hooking the `widget_posts_args` filter with `my_widget_posts_args` function.
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args');
function my_widget_posts_args($args) {
    // Look here, this is the twist.
    // with checking on `is_category()` function you are making this behavior for categories only.
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        return array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'cat' => $cat -> term_id//the current category id
        );
    }
    else {
        // If it is not category it is returning `$args` for normal behaviour.
        return $args;

    }
}
```

So for making it work on single page as well you need to modify the `if` condition block and the code block will look like below-

```
// By this below code you are returning TRUE to the filter 'tve_dash_enqueue_frontend' filter. Which is I think, is turning something on.
add_filter( 'tve_dash_enqueue_frontend', '__return_true' );

// Here you are hooking the `widget_posts_args` filter with `my_widget_posts_args` function.
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', 'my_widget_posts_args' );
function my_widget_posts_args( $args ) {
    // Look here, this is the twist.
    // with checking on `is_category()` function you are aking this behaviour for categories only.
    if ( is_category() ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        return array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'cat' => $cat -> term_id, //the current category id
        );
    } else {
        // If it is a single post then it'll return posts from the category(s) of current post.
        global $post;
        return array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'no_found_rows' => true,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
            'category__in' => get_the_category( $post->ID ),
        );

    }
}
```

> Notice: If it is a single post then it'll show posts from the category(s) of current post at widget.

Comment: @didi Please remove your comment what you did as answer and try the updated code. ***And for further communication must use comment, NOT ANSWER***

Comment: Sorry for use answer! By the way, now the error it's gone, but nothing appear in the sidebar.